# Unable to find resource ID #0x7f09001c in packages [android, org.robolectric.default]

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-activity, junit, robolectric

I'm running some tests with Roboletric, but I came across a issue that I can't solve. When I run the test, the following error appears:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f09001c in packages [android, org.robolectric.default]
>
> at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.getResName(ShadowAssetManager.java:925)
>
> at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowAssetManager.loadXmlResourceParser(ShadowAssetManager.java:439)
>
> at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.loadXmlResourceParser(ShadowResources.java:221)
>
> at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java)
>
> at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:852)
>
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
>
> at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
>
> at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
>
> at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
>
> at com.example.robertoassad.roboletrictest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
>
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
>
> at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:232)
>
> at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:58)
>
> at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:364)
>
> at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$1.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:26)
>
> at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:55)
>
> at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:65)
>
> at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.setup(ActivityController.java:157)
>
> at org.robolectric.Robolectric.setupActivity(Robolectric.java:101)
>
> at com.example.robertoassad.roboletrictest.MainActivityTest.clickingLogin_shouldStartLoginActivity(MainActivityTest.java:20)
>
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>
> at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>
> at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>
> at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>
> at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$HelperTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:523)
>
> at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$2.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:226)
>
> at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:108)
>
> at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner.runChild(SandboxTestRunner.java:35)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>
> at org.robolectric.internal.SandboxTestRunner$1.evaluate(SandboxTestRunner.java:62)
>
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>
> at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>
> at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
>
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
>
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2.main(AppMainV2.java:131)

at

> com.example.robertoassad.alltestsmerge.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)

On MainActivity.java:15 have the error is on following code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Specifically in:  `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

and on

> com.example.robertoassad.roboletrictest.MainActivityTest.clickingLogin_shouldStartLoginActivity(MainActivityTest.java:20)

On MainActivityTest.java:20 the error is specifically in:

```
MainActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
```

For me I didn't see sense in this issue ...

**DETAILS**:

The test class is on the folder: `app\src\test\java\{package}`

The test is:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest= Config.NONE)
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Test
    public void clickingLogin_shouldStartLoginActivity() {
        MainActivity activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
        activity.findViewById(R.id.login).performClick();

        Intent expectedIntent = new Intent(activity, HomeActivity.class);
        Intent actual = ShadowApplication.getInstance().getNextStartedActivity();
        assertEquals(expectedIntent.getComponent(), actual.getComponent());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***This worked for me:***

Went to [Robolectric Setup page](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/) and followed their guide to move to their latest release.

***In other words***,

- Added the latest release they had, as of Feb 17th 2017: `testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.7.1"`
- Added the `includeAndroidResources = true` in my `build.graddle`

***For instance,***

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests {
      includeAndroidResources = true
    }
  }
}
dependencies {
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.7.1"
}
```

Run my tests without any Config annotation

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MyTests {

    @Test
    public void singleTest() {
        //Do and verify or assert something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify manifest or constants in @Config so that Robolectric knows where to find the resources. Config.NONE is not going to work.

Comment: @ArtiomLK https://gist.github.com/hkhc/15c22c9eb3c8603e5fa2328e5d88cd47